# Sign in With Apple Error with 'invalid_grant' and description 'the code has already been used'

Tags: apple-sign-in

I keep getting the same "The code has already been used" error.
However, I checked that the code was redeemed within the given time (5 minutes)

```
$data = [
'client_id' => $clientId, // app id?
'client_secret' => $client_secret,
'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
'code' => $code, //from request
'redirect_uri' => $uri,
            ]; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch); //=> '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The code has already been used."}'
```

After 5 minutes , I get a new message `'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The code has expired or has been revoked."}'`

Someone to help me?

Comment: have you found a solution? I have the same pain

Answer (score 0):

I had the same `invalid_grant` "The code has expired or has been revoked." error and fought with it for days.

In my case, it seems like the Apple ID I was testing with was in some kind of invalid state where the Settings app showed my app as authorized for SIWA, but the REST API thought that access had been revoked.

I discovered this by trying a different Apple ID for troubleshooting, and not getting the `invalid_grant` error with that. This was my first indication that something was wrong with the Apple ID I had been testing with.

I decided to try completely revoking access (in Settings, Apple ID, "Apps Using Apple ID") and starting again. After that it worked as expected; I've tried signing in and out several times and the SIWA REST API returns access/refresh tokens as expected.

I can only conclude that the ID I was developing/testing with got into some kind of weird state… where the Settings app showed my app as authorized for SIWA, but the REST API thought that access had been revoked. It's worth noting that while troubleshooting this, I did revoke and re-authorize at least once or twice, and it did not seem to help those times though perhaps something else was wrong then.

I contacted Apple about this, as it seemed like a bug (or at minimum it was unexpected and undocumented behavior). Their response was terse:

"There was some server intermittent issue during that time."

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

All I can suggest is trying different Apple IDs and/or revoking/re-authorizing. Or waiting.